# Select distinctive results based on a single column without Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data (fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3757):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT 1 AS Id1, 1000 AS Id2, NULL AS Item1, 1 AS Item2 --this should be removed from my results
  UNION SELECT 1 AS Id1, 1000 AS Id2, NULL AS Item1, 2 AS Item2
  UNION SELECT 3 AS Id1, 1000 AS Id2, 0 AS Item1, 0 AS Item2
  UNION SELECT 4 AS Id1, 1000 AS Id2, 1 AS Item1, 1 AS Item2

  --BELOW DATA DIFFERS FROM THE ABOVE ONLY ON Id2
  UNION SELECT 1 AS Id1, 2000 AS Id2, NULL AS Item1, 1 AS Item2 --this should be removed from my results
  UNION SELECT 1 AS Id1, 2000 AS Id2, NULL AS Item1, 2 AS Item2
  UNION SELECT 3 AS Id1, 2000 AS Id2, 0 AS Item1, 0 AS Item2
  UNION SELECT 4 AS Id1, 2000 AS Id2, 1 AS Item1, 1 AS Item2
) AS TestData
```

I need to filter `TestData`, to get only distinct `Id1, Id2`. The results must meet the following rules:

1. All the below rules must follow the grouping on `Id2` (I mean below only applies on groups of rows that are defined by `Id2` column). This means that `TestData` data set contains two groups - `1000,2000`
2. All rows where `Item1` matches `Item2` are good, and should be **always** returned
3. If `2.` is not met, then take the row only if `Item1` is `NULL` AND `Item2` **does not have a match anywhere in the** `TestData` (rule `1.` still apply - so we need to look in the dataset by current group)

To summarize, I need to get from `TestData` all the Id's beside first rows from each group. Also, please note that I know I could simply call `SELECT DISTINCT` and have proper Id's, but this is not the case here. My problem is bigger than what I described above, and basically what I want to know, is how to remove first row from each group in data provided above, given that `Item2` already has a match in it's group (rule `3`).

Comment: This looks a LOT like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah that's a lot of homework allright. Spent half a day on this thing at work today... I don't have anything to share as I didn't try much yet. I basically rewrote crappy sql and above is the result I got stuck at before leaving the work. So maybe someone here will have any hints on how to avoid using Group By, and if not then I will probably spend another half a day tomorrow.

Comment: Can you provide the data that you would expect to be output from your sample data? I'm not certain that I understand all of your criteria.

Comment: Also, if I have a row within a grouping that has Item1 = 1, and Item2 = 2 and another that has Item1 = NULL and Item2 = 2 then should the second pair be returned? Item2 exists in the group, but it isn't in another row that would be returned.

Comment: @TomH: If you look at my `TestData`, there are 2 groups - and in each group, first and last rows have the same `Item2`. If the row does not have matching `Item1` and `Item2`, take it only if `Item2` does not exist in the current group. I put a comments in `TestData` on which rows I need to have removed.

Comment: @TomH: If we would add these two rows you described to our first group, then we would have three non matching (`Item1 <> Item2`) rows. As I need only `Id1,Id2` in my result set, I would get only distinctive rows (so I would take at least one of these three). `Id1,Id2` will vary if Item1/Item2 varies.

Answer (score 2):

This returns the rows that you are expecting. The `COALESCE` is a bit of a shortcut, so if negative values are possible in your data then you'll need to expand those parts of the query out to account for `NULL` values. You might also need to add additional checks if other columns allow `NULL` values.

```
SELECT
    T1.id1,
    T1.id2,
    T1.item1,
    T1.item2
FROM
    My_Table T1
WHERE
    COALESCE(T1.item1, -1) = COALESCE(T1.item2, -1) OR
    (
        T1.item1 IS NULL AND
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM
                My_Table T2
            WHERE
                T2.id2 = T1.id2 AND
                COALESCE(T2.item1, -1) <> COALESCE(T1.item1, -1) AND
                T2.item2 = T1.item2
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    T1.id2,
    T1.id1
```

Comment: Thank you Tom! I was struggling with similar thing when working on this solution earlier. I do not have access to ssms right now, but if I recall correctly - in my original script, I am using common table expression where you use `T1`. And where you use `T2`, I tried using my CTE for the second time, but I think I failed there. I will need to somehow instantialise my `T1` in the place where you are using `T2`. This may be difficult as my CTE is quite complex, will need to rethink that tomorrow. Thank you for your help. :)